# Putting strings into byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

I created the byte array but don't know if this is the way you put strings of numbers into it. I am new to this byte array and am having trouble knowing if I did it right.

```
public class AdditionOnlyInt implements BigInt
{
    private byte[] data;

    public AdditionOnlyInt(String number)
    { 
        data = new byte[number.length()];
        number.replace("0","");

        int i = 0;
        int counter = number.length();

        while(i<number.length())
        {
            data[i] = (byte) number.charAt(counter);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

I have to get rid of the leading zeros then put the number in the array from least significant to most significant that is the reason for the counter variable

Comment: Uhm... Why are you _trying_ to "put a string of numbers into a byte array"? Whether this is right or not comes after understanding whether it's actually what you want to do or not...

Comment: My fault read the thing wrong I knew something was not right

Comment: I doubt that you do what you want because the character `'0'` converted via casting to `byte` should result in 48 (see [asciitable](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: Why don't you use the `getBytes()` function? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
public class AdditionOnlyInt implements BigInt
    {
  private byte[] data;



   public AdditionOnlyInt(String number)
      { 
         data = new byte[number.length()];
         String num=number.replace("0","");
         int i = 0;
         int counter = number.length()-1;
        while(counter>=0)
             {
               data[i++] = Byte.parseByte(String.valueOf(num.charAt(counter--)));
             }

      }
     }
```

Comment: length()-1 is used because index of array start from 0.  num.charAt(counter--) returns a char value and the char value is converted in string by String.valuOf() method.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bug:

```
number.replace("0","");
```

Firstly, it doesn't do anything: String is immutable, so all String methods *return* a new string, so you must *assign* the return value:

```
number = number.replace("0","");
```

Secondly, this with remove *all* zeroes - leading or otherwise. Not what you want. To remove *leading* zeroes, do this:

```
number = number.replaceAll("^0+","");
```

This uses a regex to target just the leading zeroes.

Finally, if you're trying to represent the digits of a number, use `int[]` and to get the integer value of a character, subtract '0':

```
int[] data;

data[i] = number.charAt(counter) - '0'; // '0' --> 0, '1' --> 1, '2' --> 2 etc
```

Make those changes and see if you get closer.